# how to get value form Associative Arrays query string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$resturant_category_product_query = "SELECT * FROM bb_product p WHERE p.resturant_category_id ='$resturant_category_id'";
foreach ($resturant_category_product_query as $resturant_category_product) {
        $resturant_category_product_data[] = array(
            'resturant_category_id' =>$resturant_category_product['resturant_category_id'],
        );
}
```

Comment: You just need to see the documentation of [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/it/book.mysqli.php), or some tutorial.

Comment: how to get  $resturant_category_product_data[]  value

Comment: You need to execute the query, and then retrieve each returned row. Your code just sets a variable to the string of the query and then tries to treat that string as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:-

```
<?php
$mysqli_connection = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM bb_product p 
        WHERE p.resturant_category_id ='".$mysqli_connection->->real_escape_string($resturant_category_id)."'";

if ($result = $mysqli_connection ->query($sql)) 
{
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $resturant_category_product_data[] = array('resturant_category_id'=>$row['resturant_category_id']);
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

This creating an object of a connection to the database using mysqli.

Then it sets up a string of the SQL that it wants to execute. Note that it uses the connection object to use the class to escape the string (to prevent SQL injection).

The string is then used by the query method of the connection object, returning a result object.

It then does a WHILE to loop around each returned row from the result object (each row is returned by fetch_assoc as an associative array). Note that the returned row is put in to the $row variable.